# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: unresolved variable

Tags: java, methods, error-handling, compiler-errors, linkageerror

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Why can't my parameter variable be resolved to a variable?

I'm trying to create a simple program that creates two objects of the people class, give them names and make the first object ("lisa") be-friend the second object ("mark") and finally display/print out lisa's friend on screen.

But Eclipse displays the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     lisa cannot be resolved to a variable   mark cannot be
>   resolved to a variable lisa cannot be resolved to a variable  Syntax
>   error, insert ";" to complete Statement The method friend() is
>   undefined for the type People at People.main(People.java:22)

As you can tell, I'm very new to Java, so I cannot understand what the error means and how I can fix it. Your help is greatly appreciated!

**Here is my People class:**

public class People {

```
//Constructor
public void name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


// Instance variables
public String name; 
public String friend;

// Instance method
public void addFriend(String name){
name = Object1.friend();
```

}

**Here is my main method:**

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    People Object1 = new People();
    Object1.name(lisa);

    People Object2 = new People();
    Object2.name(mark);

    Object1.addFriend(lisa);

    System.out.println(Object1.friend());

}
```

}

Comment: Read the error - it says everything: the variable "lisa" is not defined! you probably meant to use the string "lisa" as a parameter. BTW `name()` is NOT a constructor.

Comment: What lisa is here ?? u didn't defined this variable here...

Comment: Hey, I realized that, but that is exactly what I'm trying to do with this line of code ( trying to make 'lisa' = name):  public String name;  and then:  Object1.name(lisa);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
People Object1 = new People();
Object1.name(lisa);
```

you should write:

```
People people = new People();
people.name("lisa");
```

Note first the quotation marks around "lisa". Without these quotation marks Java will interprete it as variable name and not as String (as required by signature of name()-method in class People. And it is a common convention in Java to write variable names like "Object1" in small letters - for code readability. Here as information [the guidelines from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: OMG Thank you! Being new to the syntax I didn't realize the importance for quotation marks and thanks for letting me know about writing object names in small letters.

Comment: @user3289740 Have added a link to code style guidelines. Happy learning.